# Database Manager can't connect to hsqldb

Tags: java, hsqldb

After inserting the data into HSQLDB, I tried using database manager to connect to it but it failed to connect.

i launched the hsqldb in standalone mode. here is the error message:

```
Connection to HSQLDB (Local) - target failed Database lock acquisition failure: 
lockFile: org.hsqldb.persist.LockFile@a9e38b36[file =C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.2\bin\target\misc.lck, exists=false, locked=false, valid=false, ] 
method: openRAF 
reason: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.2\bin\target\misc.lck (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Comment: what is the error you get ?...stack trace ?

Comment: Code, errors? Please provide more information and possibly a minimum working example or such code that exposes the location in your code that you think might be at fault here.

Comment: i launched the hsqldb in standalone mode. 
here is the error message:
`Connection to HSQLDB (Local) - target failed
Database lock acquisition failure: lockFile: org.hsqldb.persist.LockFile@a9e38b36[file =C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.2\bin\target\misc.lck, exists=false, locked=false, valid=false, ] method: openRAF reason: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 15.0.2\bin\target\misc.lck (The system cannot find the path specified)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are launch the hsqldb in standalone mode. It will happen like you said.

In this mode. DB engine will share the same jvm as application, the process will be faster than server mode. but the bad thing is you can't access it from outside. including database manager.

If you want view the data by tools. Please launching the db in server mode